# Iteratively merging consecutive symbols of a discrete random process

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes

Consider an i.i.d. source (more generally, an ergodic source) which generates symbols from a distribution $P$ over a finite alphabet $\mathcal{A}$. Consider the following stochastic process: At each time $t \ge 1$, pick a pair of consecutive symbols according to some rule (say, the highest frequency pair, for instance), and merge them into a new symbol. Then, replace every occurrence of this pair of symbols (breaking ties randomly) by the new symbol. Repeat until some stopping criteria is met (for instance - no consecutive pair of symbols repeats more than once).

Has this, or a related model been studied in any capacity in the literature of stochastic processes? What can be said about the set of symbols (in terms of the substrings they map to in $\mathcal{A}^\star$) generated by this random process?